# piwik logs not showing in database

Tags: matomo

I've got a basic webserver and an piwik installation. I've added:

```
_paq.push([function() {
  console.log(`this.visitorInfo() = `, this.getVisitorInfo());
}]);
```

just after trackPageView, so I can see that I've got all the appropriate visitor info from piwik, and I can see in the apache logs and the browser network tab, that piwik is being called successfully.

However, when I look in the database `piwik_log_visit` table, there is no record of my visit.

Is piwik somehow caching this data and updating the database offline, or am I missing something somewhere?

Any help much appreciated. All the best,
Craig

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have added a plugin like [queued tracking](https://plugins.piwik.org/QueuedTracking), Piwik processes incoming requests immediately. But there are some reasons why your requests might not be recorded as described in [Piwik's FAQ](https://piwik.org/faq/troubleshooting/#faq_58). A very popular reason is:

> Piwik by default supports DoNotTrack: please check you haven’t enabled
>   DoNotTrack in your browser options.